# proof upon proof

Tags: meaning

What is the meaning of 'proof upon proof' in the sentence: 
"Piaget and his many collaborators had seemingly collected proof upon proof of young children’s inability to understand arithmetic."

Comment: related:[What's the difference in meaning between “evidence” and “proof”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/203640/whats-the-difference-in-meaning-between-evidence-and-proof?rq=1)

Comment: @Mari-LouA - This question doesn't mention 'evidence', nor does it request the meaning of 'proof' as a word on its own so I'm not sure how it is related to the other question.

Comment: @chaslyfromUK  The answers describe the meaning of *proof* very well, I think. Do you know if the OP understands the term *proof*, I don't.

Comment: It's proofs all the way down...

Comment: @mathallica, if you return: Please be explicit in questions about what it is that you do not understand (for example, here it appears to be *upon,* rather than *proof*), and please show evidence of what you have looked up, in order that others don't repeat a fruitless search.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Proof upon proof" means a large amount of evidence (or proofs.)

> **layer upon layer/mile upon mile**: used to emphasize that there are a
>   lot of layers, miles etc.
>
> Example: *mile upon mile of golden sand*

(Longman, the entry on "upon")